# passing unique identifier as parameter to the SQL Query function

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my 'SQL' Query and have to pass the 'UserId' as the unique identifier to 'where' clause in the Query.

```
SELECT aspnet_Roles.RoleName, aspnet_Roles.Description
FROM aspnet_Roles INNER JOIN
     aspnet_UsersInRoles ON aspnet_Roles.RoleId =  aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId INNER JOIN
     aspnet_Users ON aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
WHERE (aspnet_Users.UserId = @param)
```

And the C# code where i want to pass the parameter is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class Forms_RolesMgt_RoleList_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DSRolesTableAdapters.aspnet_RoleUsersTableAdapter userRoleAdapter = new DSRolesTableAdapters.aspnet_RoleUsersTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Guid user = Guid.NewGuid();
        user = Guid.Parse(Session["UserId"] as string);
        Response.Write(user);
        dt = userRoleAdapter.GetDataByUserId(user);//At this line i am passing the parameter and getting the error
        UserRolesGrdView.DataSource = dt;
        UserRolesGrdView.DataBind(); 
    }
  }
}
```

> Error while running: Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
>
> Error in .xsd file while preview the data by query is: Failed to covert parameter value string to Guid

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: `Failed to covert parameter value string to Guid`. how are your passing the parameter to the Sql Command? add that code as well

Comment: Can you please show the code of the function `GetDataByUserId`?

Comment: GetDataByUserId is the sql query mentioned above @Sachin

Comment: You would probably have the c# function named `GetDataByUserId` in your code. I would like to see the code for that not the query. As I want to see how are you passing the parameter `@param` to the query.

Comment: It seems that you've already asked this question here and accepted the solution as well. http://forums.asp.net/t/2044556.aspx?Failed+To+Convert+parameter+value+from+a+String+to+Guide.

Comment: @Sachin i checked your comment just now, it seems my answer is somehow same as in the url you have given.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Name]  
(@param uniqueidentifier
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT aspnet_Roles.RoleName, aspnet_Roles.Description
    FROM aspnet_Roles INNER JOIN
    aspnet_UsersInRoles ON aspnet_Roles.RoleId = aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId INNER JOIN
    aspnet_Users ON aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
    WHERE (aspnet_Users.UserId = @param)
END
```

And add parameter for the sp in GetDataByUserId() method as:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@param",SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value=userId;
```